# Using a Color struct in a buffer/array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, endianness

I'm working on a library that handles (among others) images. For interoperability with OGL I need (at least) to write to BGRA buffers (byte order -> B first)
For that I'm designing a ColorARGB class that should represent a color. I have 2 approaches in mind: The first one stores the color value as an `uint32_t` and provides conversion methods to byte buffers and the second stores the components as bytes and should be able to be used directly. In code:

```
struct ColorARGB
{
    uint32_t clrValue;
    ColorARGB(uint32_t clrValue):clrValue(clrValue){}
    ColorARGB(uint8_t a, uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b)
    {
        clrValue = a << 24 | r << 16 | g << 8 | b;
    }
    static ColorARGB fromBGRA(const uint8_t* ptr)
    {
        return fromBGRA(reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(ptr));
    }

    static ColorARGB fromBGRA(const uint32_t* ptr)
    {
        // This is little endian BGRA word format
        return ColorARGB(boost::endian::little_to_native(*ptr));
    }
    // Similar functions for toBGRA
}
```

or:

```
struct ColorARGB2{
    uint8_t clrValues[4]; // Or maybe: uint8_t b, g, r, a;
    ColorARGB2(uint8_t a, uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b)
    {
        clrValues[0] = b; clrValues[1] = g;
        clrValues[2] = r; clrValues[3] = a;
    }
}
```

The second version should allow `std::vector<ColorARGB2>` while the first one would have the problem, that on big endian machines the buffer is ARGB not BGRA. I can also just `reinterpret_cast<ColorARGB2*>` while it isn't possible for for `ColorARGB` for the endianess reason.

Is there anything wrong with ColorARGB2? Would I run into possible alignment issues especially when handling byte buffers (`uint8_t*`)? Can I simply implement the comparison as `reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(&lhs) == reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(&rhs)` or could this fail due to alignment?

Update (not a real answer but helps):
I found the following of use in the boost src code:

```
#if defined(__x86_64__) || defined(_M_X64) || defined(__i386) || defined(_M_IX86)
    // On x86 (which is little endian), unaligned loads are permitted
#   define RTTR_USE_UNALIGNED_ACCESS 1
#endif
```

Comment: Interestingly enough I wrote up a code sample for an SO answer a few days ago. It used a simple "color" type to demonstrate a point. You can [check it out here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17d83c4719892da5). It uses a union to give you something that is option 1 with a bit of option 2.

Comment: You should also know that unless you pass the address of a `uint32_t` to begin with into `fromBGRA(uint8_t)`, you will have UB. That is, if you intend to pass in an array of `uint8_t` and just alias it as `uint32_t`, you'll be in violation of the strict aliasing rule.

Comment: Is it really a violation of the strict aliasing rule? Because I thought it only refers to "pointer arguments to functions". Here I only have 1 argument.

Comment: Any access to a variable other than with an lvalue of character type or it's own type is officially undefined behavior. You can access a `uint32_t` with a `uint8_t*` (assuming it's an alias for unsigned char), but you can't access what is initially an array of `uint_t8` by a `uint32_t*`.

Comment: So what would be a good solution for my case? As according to this even reinterpret-casting to `ColorARGB2` would be UB.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you could hit alignment issues, but in practice, I've never seen it happen for a situation like this.

There is also a 3rd option you haven't enumerated, and that is to do both by using a union. Something along the lines of:

```
typedef union ARGBPixel {
    uint32_t colorValue;
    uint8_t components[4];  // <- Or an existing struct with separate a,r,g,b
} ARGBPixel;
```

With the above union the same piece of memory can be addressed as either a `uint32_t` or an array or struct of `uint8_t`s.

Comment: AFAIK you are not supposed to read from a union member to which you have not written. I was thinking about this but got the feeling it just adds another point of failure.